# How do I implement saving 1000s of records using CloudKit and Swift without exceeding 30 or 40 requests/second

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Let me describe the basic flow that I am trying to implement:

1. User logs in
2. System retrieves list of user's connections using HTTP request to 3rd party API (could be in the 1000s).  I'll call this list **userConnections**
3. System retrieves stored connections from my app's database (could be in the 100,000s).  I'll call this list **connections**
4. System then checks to see if each **userConnection** exists in the **connections** list already and if not, saves it to database:

   ```
   for userConnection in userConnections {
       if connections.contains(userConnection) {
       //do nothing
       } else {
        saveRecord(userConnection)
       }
     }
   ```

The problem with this is that when the first users log in, the app will try to make 1000 saveRecord calls in a second which the CloudKit server will not allow.

How can I implement this in a different way using CloudKit and Swift so that I keep it to an acceptable number of requests/second, like ~30 or 40?

Comment: I believe you can batch save your records. See [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-715/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this is how I ended up doing it.  The comment by TroyT was correct that you can batch save your records.  This answer includes bonus of queued batches:

```
        let save1 = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: list1, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
        let save2 = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: list2, recordIDsToDelete: nil)

        save1.database = publicDB
        save2.database = publicDB

        save2.addDependency(save1)
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        queue.addOperations([save1, save2], waitUntilFinished: false)

        save1.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordsIDs, error  in
            if (error != nil){
                //handle error
            }else{
                //data saved
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can't try to save 1000 records at a time, the server will give you a limit error. I believe the maximum is 400. Then, you can create the operations with dependency or a big operation giving batches at a time. I think every batch is only one request.